# Interpret HTML String from re-frame clojurescript app

Tags: dom, clojurescript, reagent

I want to connect an re-frame clojurescript app to a headless content manager to get posts. The content is returned to me as a string with HTML tag - something like below:

```
<h1>dsfdsfdsf</h1><p>ddsfdsf</p>
```

I went straight to display the string and ended with the full string with tags displayed...
I read around that I need to access the DOM to with an interpreter.

I tried the below function

```
(defn parse-html [html]
  "Parse an html string into a document"
  (let [doc (.createHTMLDocument js/document.implementation "mydoc")]
    (set! (.-innerHTML doc.documentElement) html)
    doc
    ))
```

```
(parse-html "<div><p>some of my stuff</p></div>")
```

but ended with the error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDocument]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Can someone advise me a way to render the html from the string.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replaced the `re-frame` tag with a more appropriate `reagent` - the library that re-frame itself uses for rendering.

In React, you do that via the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute that receives unparsed HTML.

In Reagent, and consequently re-frame, in order to use that attribute you have to write something like:

```
(defn wrap-html [html]
  [:div {:dangerouslySetInnerHTML {:__html html}}])
```

Comment: it works indeed that way. Thanks a lot. Just a last question, how did you figured out the writing - any docs? Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, plenty. Everything is documented. https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html